# Cannot make height 100% of div

Tags: html, css

I have tried multiple things but for some reason no matter what I tray I cannot make my inner divs height 100% of the page, and it leaves me with half page looking divs through out my site. I think a part of the problem is because I have a fixed footer but I cant figure out or find a way around this, especially because I want the site to be responsive. Here is an example of the problem on my site that shows the problem. I believe I need the height of "container-fluid" div to be 100%.

to clarify, I want the white part to be stretched till the bottom of the page.

site link: http://steppy.herokuapp.com/users/new

Comment: Looks like 100% of the site how do you mean 100%? Clear your cache or visit the site in incognito mode?

Comment: sorry I should've clarified, I want the white part to be stretched till the bottom of the page.

Comment: You want the sticky footer to be x pixels beneath the visible bottom of the page?

Comment: thanks for your reply, not quite, I want the grey part of appcont to extend all the way to the footer on every page, even if the content is not enough inside to push it all the way down. does that make sense?

Comment: When I visit the site, the footer is already at the window bottom, and the grey area is pushing it to the bottom...

Comment: it might depend on resolution, but for me for instance, there is a white space between the grey area and the footer at the bottom,

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
bottom: -70px;
```

to the

```
.footer2
```

so it looks like this to in your css:

```
  .footer2 {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #212A34;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 70px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: -70px;
    }
```

this way the footer will be 70 pixels beneath the white background this way the user will need to scroll down in order to see the footer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is the webpage is virtually infinite, so your saying 100% of infinity, which the browser cannot interpret. You may see your div smashed into a small space based on how much content is in it. So if there were a sentence in the div, and the div height was 100%, then the div would be the same height as the amount of text in the sentence. I had this same problem when doing a background image. Your best hope is to follow the advice above and give a pixel length or any other length. How can you have a percentage of basically infinity?

Hope this added to your knowledge and helped a little bit!

Comment: ah I see, so in order for it work i guess i would need a definite height for instance on my body? bcuz then it wouldnt be infinite, but then how can it scale responsively?

Comment: Yes Correct @user2472480 . You don't exactly have to 'scale' per-say but a definite height, no matter how large or small would be good. I usually make the web page as wide as the screen, because in the long run, width will affect things like smaller screens, height could be anything